# Why I cannot call my function (order_detail)in django admin file?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:

> <class 'orders.admin.OrderAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of
> 'list_display[10]' refers to 'order_detail', which is not a callable,
> an attribute of 'OrderAdmin', or an attribute or method on
> 'orders.Order'.
>
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

my django admin.py

```
def order_detail(obj):
    return '<a href="{}">View</a>'.format(reverse('orders:admin_order_detail',
                                                  args=[obj.id]))


order_detail.allow_tags = True


# @admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                    'address', 'postal_code', 'city', 'paid', 'created', 'updated', 'order_detail']
    list_filter = ['paid', 'created', 'updated']
    inlines = [OrderItemInline]
    actions = [export_to_csv]


admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Comment: Change `'order_detail'` to `order_detail`.

Comment: Thank You sir, I  assumed I have to pass a string to display_list

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `'order_detail'` to `order_detail`.

Strings will be interpreted by django as attribute of the model or admin class. Specifying `order_detail` will inform django that it is a callable.